# How do you get the index of a tag when it is selected in TTGTagCollectionView

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, cocoapods

here is the documentation for the library TTGTagCollectionView  https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView on github.

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in the description at the link you provided.

If you're asking how to do it in Swift:

```
func textTagCollectionView(_ textTagCollectionView: TTGTextTagCollectionView!, didTapTag tagText: String!, at index: UInt, selected: Bool, tagConfig config: TTGTextTagConfig!) {
    // Tag was tapped... do what you want
    print("Index:", index, "Selected:", selected, "TagText:", tagText ?? "No Text")
}
```